# Should you specify the parent object in javascript when using the alert method?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and noticed the following two syntaxes achieve the same end goal:

```
window.alert("chitty chitty bang bang!");
alert("chitty chitty bang bang!");
```

Also, why doesn't this syntax work?

```
window.document.alert("chitty chitty bang bang!");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window` is kind of the global scope of javascript. If you don't specify a scope when calling a javascript function, this parent global scope is always assumed. As far as why `window.document.alert` doesn't work is concerned, well, it's because the `alert` function has been defined on the `window` global object and not on the `window.document` object which represents the DOM.

Comment: Great answers, I feel luck to have two experts answer this for me.  Can you recommend any websites where I can learn javascript?

Comment: @LedZeppelin, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646032/whats-the-best-javascript-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

`alert` is a method of `window`, not `document`.

Since `window` is the global object in in-browser Javascript, `alert` refers to `window.alert`.

Answer (score 1):

`alert` is a `window` method, so no, you don't have to use that because it's the top most object (the 'global scope') for your scripting. `alert` is not a method of `document`, that's why `window.document.alert("chitty chitty bang bang!");` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

`alert` is a global method defined under `window` object. so `window.alert` or `alert` both give the same result. Any variable defined globally can be accessed with window object.

Because `alert` is a memeber of `window` object, `window.document.alert` will not work.